# finding checked radio button in asp.net mvc 3 controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an asp.net MVC 3 razor view which generates checkboxes like this:

```
 @foreach (LoanQuestionIncludesStatement statement in item.Statements)
                {
                    _question = statement.Question;                  
                    @Html.RadioButton("_Q_" + counter.ToString("0#") + _question.ToString(), false, new { @class = "answer " + qOrderedClass, id = "_Q_" + questionOrderedNumber }) @statement.Statement
                    @Html.Hidden("_S_" + counter.ToString("0#") + _question.ToString(), statement.KeyOrStatement) 
                    <br />
                    counter++;
                }
```

Here is the html generated:

```
<div id="result">
    Please check the correct answer to each of the following questions.
<form method="post" id="frmLoanAuth" action="/CreditRegistry/Verify/VerifyByAccountInfo">        <ol>
        <li class="loanauthquestion">
            <b>Your other obligor's name is</b> <div>
<input type="radio" value="False" name="_Q_002" id="_Q_0" class="answer _QO0">Ann Fillmore<input type="hidden" value="Ann Fillmore" name="_S_002">                    <br>
<input type="radio" value="False" name="_Q_012" id="_Q_0" class="answer _QO0">Alexander Cleveland<input type="hidden" value="Alexander Cleveland" name="_S_012">                    <br>
<input type="radio" value="False" name="_Q_022" id="_Q_0" class="answer _QO0">Abraham Reagan<input type="hidden" value="Abraham Reagan" name="_S_022">                    <br>

                <input type="radio" value="False" name="_N_002" id="_Q_0" class="noneabove _QO0">None of above<br>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="loanauthquestion">
            <b>Your guarantor or co-signer's name is</b> <div>
<input type="radio" value="False" name="_Q_035" id="_Q_1" class="answer _QO1">Jude Taylor plc<input type="hidden" value="733824657071694816" name="_S_035">                    <br>
<input type="radio" value="False" name="_Q_045" id="_Q_1" class="answer _QO1">Felix Cleveland plc<input type="hidden" value="733824657071861723" name="_S_045">                    <br>
<input type="radio" value="False" name="_Q_055" id="_Q_1" class="answer _QO1">Eve Cameron plc<input type="hidden" value="733824657071409055" name="_S_055">                    <br>

                <input type="radio" value="False" name="_N_005" id="_Q_1" class="noneabove _QO1">None of above<br>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="loanauthquestion">
            <b>Your account balance in a history is in between</b> <div>
<input type="radio" value="False" name="_Q_0610" id="_Q_2" class="answer _QO2">$288,518.79 - $362,585.72<input type="hidden" value="$288,518.79 - $362,585.72" name="_S_0610">                    <br>
<input type="radio" value="False" name="_Q_0710" id="_Q_2" class="answer _QO2">$439,500.00 - $886,344.32<input type="hidden" value="$439,500.00 - $886,344.32" name="_S_0710">                    <br>
<input type="radio" value="False" name="_Q_0810" id="_Q_2" class="answer _QO2">$-51,500.00 - $1,050,052.31<input type="hidden" value="$-51,500.00 - $1,050,052.31" name="_S_0810">                    <br>

                <input type="radio" value="False" name="_N_0010" id="_Q_2" class="noneabove _QO2">None of above<br>
            </div>
        </li>
        </ol>
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="_accountInfoQoNumber" id="_accountInfoQoNumber"><input type="hidden" value="GJMgySz1thj6chtAmRJGr/MaT0YdCY24DZfD1OKju9o5byr/sRPw86gKdEOjjmWGUmSfZ+RJ6AcVVnplGRSiNgFshxaqeRSS/7xAOz3T+q1lEek5whYUL7ggW+PXTX+wVfsNMUrMdeVVVHFjJYYYntxjwt8USjxzY2K0cnDsFqK2vxwa" name="__RequestVerificationToken">        <p><input type="submit" class="readon button" value="Verify"></p>
</form></div>
```

1. I want to make sure that only one radiobutton is checked in one group which is not happening
2. I want to check in controller action which radiobutton is checked, how can i do this?

I am using this code in controller action:

```
  var questionRequests = from x in Request.Form.AllKeys
                                   where x.StartsWith("_Q_")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that only one radiobutton is checked in one group you must give same name to all those radiobuttons in that group.

Comment: @ G.R. How to get selected one ?

Comment: Give Formcollection formobj as one of the parameter of the post Action and iterate through all radiobuttons and check if value is on or off.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow Only checked value you will get with POST in action, so value must contain `id` or something else.

Comment: you can get all the values in the controller by taking formobj["your_radio_name"].It will be on if selected and off if unselected

Comment: But after your post they will have same name for group, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

`id` must be unique and `name` attribute the same for grouping

Look at this url: [html radio button](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm)